# How to package a BAT in Visual installer and how to run a BAT file during MSI installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have a BAT file with this content:

```
"XYNTService.exe" "-i"
```

I am currently building up an installation package using Visual Studio Installer. I added this BAT file inside the `Application Folder`. Now I want to execute it during installation process. How can it be done?

I have surf a lot about custom actions, but still fail to understand how to do it. Need help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you can always run a batch file by doing ShellExecute or CreateProcess on cmd.exe with the relevant parameters.

However, rememeber that MSI custom actions run in a different user context from the user who is installing. You may struggle to get the batch file to do what you want to.

Martyn

Comment: now i understand. my BAT file or my EXE file cannot execute because it is not even written yet to the disk. This is because the files only written when I click 'close' at the final screen of the MSI. now my problem is, how to execute a command after I close the msi..