# How to package a powershell script in Visual Installer and how to run a ps1 file during MSI installation?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, windows-installer, installation

I've created an msi installer with Visual installer but I would like to add a powershell script (script.ps1) to the installer. The script should be executed during the MSI installation.

I have added the script.ps1 in the application folder but how do I execute it during the installation?

Do I have to add a registry key that will contain the command:

```
powershell -file "C:\script.ps1"
```

I failed to understand how to achieve my goal. I found a post that asks the same question but for bat files but there isn't much solutions and I don't understand the tip which is given in the post. Here is [a link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658887/how-to-package-a-bat-in-visual-installer-and-how-to-run-a-bat-file-during-msi-in).